# Sequence operations

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have a little card playing app. When the computer is playing, some functions are being fired after some time to mimic a real player, like so:

```
self.operation.addOperation {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now()+2) {
        self.passTurn()
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I want to cancel the game and start a new one, the app crashes if I do it within two seconds before the `self.passTurn()` function fires.

Ideally I would like to have some sort of pause between the different operations. The above mentioned operation gets released from the queue immediately after it fires the delayed function, so cancelling or suspends the operation does not work.

Is it possible to somehow retain the operation in the queue for two seconds and release it afterwards when the actual function is done?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than using the convenience function `asyncAfter` create a one-shot `DispatchSourceTimer` which can be cancelled

Comment: What is actually crashing?

Comment: @shim a player from the game should pass, but when I create a new game, this player does not exist anymore. So it crashes because player is nil.

Comment: Why can't you check to see if a player is nil so the crash doesn't happen?

Comment: @shim Thought of that, but I want to have a little more control by pausing, cancelling, resuming, etc.